# Search substring inside ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, substring

I've the following code (simplified):

```
 InputStream from = ...
 ByteArrayOutputStream answer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 String res = "";

 int maxn = 1024;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[maxn]; 
 while( true ) {
    int a = from.available();
    if( a > 0 ) {
        if( a > maxn ) a = maxn;
        a = from.read( buffer, 0, a );
        answer.write( buffer, 0, a );

        res = answer.toString();
        if( res.contains( "myprompt" ) ) return res;
    }
}
```

there are any method of skip the conversion of answer from to String at each iteration, just to check if it contains "myprompt" ?

It seems something inefficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't have any query methods other than those that create new objects and return all contents in them.

Why use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all if you discard it anyway? You can use a `StringBuilder` which contains an `indexOf()` method that can search for a substring.

[edit] And a kind warning regarding character encodings: `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` uses the platform default encoding,whether you like it or not. Similarly, appending bytes to `StringBuilder` will use the equivalent of ISO_8859_1 (i.e. one byte → one char), whether you like it or not. If you need a specific encoding, you need another approach, and it won't be as efficient as `StringBuilder` (but more efficient than your current implementation).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. StringBuild has no append/insert of byte[]. However, taken into accout your answer, probably I will use StringBuild, doing conversion of each slice.

Comment: I implied converting each byte to char, hence ISO_8859_1.

Comment: If you're using another encoding, you've got a problem. you're receiving the data asynchronously, so there's no telling if the data is cut off in the middle of a codepoint. Worst case example, if the data is UTF16 and you receive two byte arrays of an odd length, how do you suppose to decode the character in the middle?